# How the Python suffixes obtained by imp.get_suffixes() are set (in particular in Debian Jessie)?

Tags: debian, python, configure

The command

```
python -c "import imp; print(imp.get_suffixes())"
```

prints a list of tuples with suffixes used when importing modules (see [the doc of imp.get_suffixes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.get_suffixes)). Usually it is simply:

```
[('.so', 'rb', 3), ('module.so', 'rb', 3), ('.py', 'U', 1), ('.pyc', 'rb', 2)]
```

However, on Debian jessie, there is another suffix:

```
[('.x86_64-linux-gnu.so', 'rb', 3), ('.so', 'rb', 3), ('module.so', 'rb', 3), ('.py', 'U', 1), ('.pyc', 'rb', 2)]
```

and some extensions have the suffix `.x86_64-linux-gnu.so`, for example `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paraview/vtkCommonCorePython.x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

I would like to use extensions that have this suffix with a Python that is not the system Python and that I built myself, but it doesn't work because this Python doesn't have the suffix `.x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

So I wonder how I can add this suffix. It seems that there is no function like `imp.add_suffix`. I suspect it is done during the building of Python but I wonder how... I looked at the source of the Debian Python packages, but it is not simple and I didn't manage to get how it works...

Answer (score 1):

Just got the same problem. Using the information provided in this thread I was able to go further.

I used `apt source python2.7` and `debuild -b -uc -us` to inspect in detail how the official package was built. Implementation of `imp.get_suffixes()` is at Python/import.c:2940 `imp_get_suffixes(...)` which reads suffixes from list named `_PyImport_Filetab`. This list, in turn, is basically `_PyImport_DynLoadFiletab` and `_PyImport_StandardFiletab` concatenated.

It became obvious that `_PyImport_DynLoadFiletab` is what we should be looking for, and its definition varies for different platform - they are in Python/dynload_*.c. In Python/dynload_shlib.c is:

```
const struct filedescr _PyImport_DynLoadFiletab[] = {
#ifdef __CYGWIN__
    {".dll", "rb", C_EXTENSION},
    {"module.dll", "rb", C_EXTENSION},
#else
#if defined(PYOS_OS2) && defined(PYCC_GCC)
    {".pyd", "rb", C_EXTENSION},
    {".dll", "rb", C_EXTENSION},
#else
#ifdef __VMS
    {".exe", "rb", C_EXTENSION},
    {".EXE", "rb", C_EXTENSION},
    {"module.exe", "rb", C_EXTENSION},
    {"MODULE.EXE", "rb", C_EXTENSION},
#else
#ifdef Py_DEBUG
    {"_d.so", "rb", C_EXTENSION},
    {"module_d.so", "rb", C_EXTENSION},
# ifdef MULTIARCH
    {"." MULTIARCH "_d.so", "rb", C_EXTENSION},
# endif
#endif
#ifdef MULTIARCH
    {"." MULTIARCH ".so", "rb", C_EXTENSION},
#endif
    {".so", "rb", C_EXTENSION},
    {"module.so", "rb", C_EXTENSION},
#endif
#endif
#endif
    {0, 0}
};
```

It's right there: `MULTIARCH`, if you go look at the build log, is `"x86_64-linux-gnu"` (with quotes, because of the `-`s). The value is apparently from `dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH` but I have not verified.

More importantly, `_PyImport_DynLoadFiletab` does not look like this originally in dynload_shlib.c, it was patched. So to get the same behavior one must also apply some patch, at least add the `{"." MULTIARCH ".so", ...}` part. In my case patching this file (dynload_shlib.c) alone seems sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You should compile your not-system-python after configuring it with the same setup of Debian's python. One way to "retrieve" this is from the [sysconfig](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sysconfig.html) module.

```
python -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_vars()['CONFIG_ARGS'])"
```

gives you something like:

```
'--enable-shared' '--prefix=/usr' '--enable-ipv6' '--enable-unicode=ucs4' '--with-dbmliborder=bdb:gdbm' '--with-system-expat' '--with-system-ffi' '--with-fpectl' 'CC=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' 'CFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro'
```

which you would have to pass on to `./configure` in the Python source directory.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on sysconfig.get_config_vars but unfortunately, it does not work. I tried and the new Python has always the same suffixes... without ``.x86_64-linux-gnu.so``...

Comment: @paugier Sorry for the misleading information. I was pretty sure this was "just" a configuration issue. I will have to see if I can find my notes on this somewhere

Comment: @paugier I compared all the `get_config_vars()` output between the system Python  and my own build. The main difference is that Debian's has a `multiarchsubdir` key. Maybe [this link](https://wiki.debian.org/Python/MultiArch) can help you further, although I don't see a direct description on how to set that up for any python (if it was simple they would have done so for 2.6/3.2 as well.